# Sine and Cosine ERROR on Answer

Tags: vb.net, math, operators, trigonometry

Recently, I use this code in finding the sine and cosine. Yet I have problems on the output/answer to any given. Kindly please help me and show me the proper code in finding the sine and cosine of the given number?

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim md1x, md1y, md2x, md2y, md3x, md3y, totalX, totalY, rv As Double

    md1x = TextBox1.Text * Math.Cos(TextBox2.Text)
    md1y = TextBox1.Text * Math.Cos(TextBox2.Text)
    md2x = TextBox4.Text * (Cos(TextBox5.Text))
    md2y = TextBox4.Text * (Sin(TextBox5.Text))
    md3x = TextBox7.Text * (Cos(TextBox8.Text))
    md3y = TextBox7.Text * (Sin(TextBox8.Text))
    totalX = md1x + md2x + md3x
    totalY = md1y + md2y + md3y
    rv = Sqrt(totalX ^ 2 + totalY ^ 2)

    TextBox16.Text = md1x
    TextBox15.Text = md1y
    TextBox14.Text = md2x
    TextBox13.Text = md2y
    TextBox12.Text = md3x
    TextBox11.Text = md3y
    TextBox10.Text = rv
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: What is in the `TextBox`s when you get to this point?  We can't debug what we can't see (although my best guess is what Eric J answered).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not understanding trig functions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what the actual problem is, but a very common problem is that the angle is expected in **radians** rather than **degrees**

> The angle, d, must be in radians. Multiply by Math.PI/180 to convert degrees to radians.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, `TextBox2.Text` (etc) is of type `string`, not of type `double`.

Try something like

```
md1x = double.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * (Math.Cos(double.Parse(TextBox2.Text)))
```

For more error tolerance, you can use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, providing appropriate messages to the UI if parsing fails.

NOTE: double.Parse(...) is the C# syntax.  I expect the VB.Net syntax will be similar.  Anyone feel free to edit this answer to correct the syntax if necessary.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if one wants optimal accuracy when using degrees, one should convert a sine or cosine computation to one in the range +/- 45 degrees, and then convert the resulting angle to radians.  Using that approach will yield sinDegrees(180), CosineDegrees(90), and CosineDegrees(270), all equal to zero, whereas there exists no number of non-zero representable number of radians such that Sin(x)=0, nor does there exist any representable number of radians such that Cos(x)=0.

Comment: The text in your question still does not show you trying to parse the .Text properties into a double. Also, what input are you using?

Comment: SOLVED sir. (y) I'd just converted the inputted number to radians before I find the sine and cosine of the given number. Thanks so much! :)